# How to achieve spring Hateoas in the current Rest API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

I have successfully implemented RestFul API as per the standards but have not incorporated all of the features in my API. For instance, my API currently adheres to the URI standard and the proper verb usage as per the explained standards. What I want to achieve is an API with level 3 implementation according to this article

> http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/beyond-rest-how-to-build-a-hateoas-api-in-java-with-spring-mvc-jersey-jax-rs-and-vraptor/

That means I am trying to implement HATEOAS in my restful API. I have started reading the articles to understand about it and have got a blurry vision to get what I want. What I need is to have a basic plan as to what steps are important for HATEOAS ?

Alright, I have a Rest API which sends the request postcode to a service

> http://localhost:8080/api/india/{postcode}

Here postcode being the path parameter.

When called, it responds back with all the possible address matches for that particular postcode.
Now, the API i have made is giving the proper response in both xml and json format and I have no complains. Now, as the next step I need to implement the feature HATEOAS 
in this API. I have got the basic understanding of HATEOAS but how would it work for my API is my query.

Comment: What is the exact problem you have with HATEOAS?

Comment: The problem with Hateoas for a new developer like me is that the articles and examples give a lot to process. I would like to have a simple explanation of how to achieve it in my API.

Comment: So the questions is really: What is HATEOAS in a nutshell?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Well yes.. but if you want to share articles about hateoas, i might have already read those. I have also made the sample application on Hateoas with the help of Spring Hateoas documentation. But I don't think that would be enough to understand HATEOAS for my particular API

Comment: Sorry, in that case we are back to square one: Please provide a more specific question.

Comment: Hi Jens, I have just edited my question to explain the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind HATEOAS is that you need no up front knowledge of an API except an initial URL.

In your case this might be the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/
```

The resource on that URL might contain a list of links for various countries, leading to

```
http://localhost:8080/api/india
http://localhost:8080/api/china
http://localhost:8080/api/australia
```

and so on. In those resources there might be further links or a form or both leading to

```
http://localhost:8080/api/india/{postcode}
```

Of course you might have a form on the first page, leading directly to the final URL and many variation more.

The result of this design is, that your application can change the urls at any time, without breaking anything.

One important implementation detail is that of 'rel' for communicating the purpose of the link. The interpretation of that purpose actually has to go into the implementation of the client, which is a bummer, but I guess until there is a really strong AI implemented in all http clients, this is the only choice we have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jens, I was going through some of the Hateoas tutorial links and found https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/ as a starting tutorial. But I still am clueless as to how I should implement this in my API ?